# Get notifications from computer to phone

Tags: c#, notifications, message

The question below is more for ideas, guidance and directions than coding assistance. Sorry if I am in the wrong place.

I have a console application which is checking for a specific file on my computer on a specific path. I want to get a notification when it detects the file on my phone.

What is the best way to get this done, if there is one.

I though about using facebook to simply send me a message but after a little research I found out that FB prevents people from sending private messages to avoid abusive usage of it.

Is there another easy way to do this?

Comment: you could send sms with something like https://www.twilio.com/sms if you are willing to pay.

Comment: "The question below does not meet the SO guidelines but I'm going to ask anyway."

Comment: I found a lot of solutions and thank you for the answer. But it is not so important that I am willing to pay.

Comment: @DanWilson I believe you understood the point. You can vote it down but lets not get away from the topic please

Comment: Most phones have an email address like 2027710384@mobile.att.net. You could try that. Sending real SMS messages will always cost money.

Comment: @DanWilson actually simply sending an email could do the trick. I will give it a try, thank you

Comment: I was just being snarky.

Comment: @DanWilson Add that as an answer. It did the trick. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most phones have an email address like 2027710384@mobile.att.net. I have had success doing that in the past as a workaround.

Here is a list of provider addresses: http://www.sensiblesoftware.com/weblog/2011/02/28/cell-phone-email-addresses/

In my application I stored the user's phone number and provider. When sending a notification, I simply put the two together and send an email message.

Sending real SMS messages will always cost money because you have to pay for usage of telephony infrastructure.